# dns query regarding web server

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, web-server

We have a private network in office through a ADSL modem which connects to the internet. 
All our IP address are in the subnet 192.168.0.XX .

We have a web server running on 192.168.0.140 (Centos PC ). In the vhosts configuration of apache we have named the server as myhost. I can access the http://myhost in that PC since I have also added an entry in /etc/hosts file .
192.168.0.140 myhost.

But from the other PC's We are not able to access http://myhost .

I suspect this is a DNS problem .

Could anyone tell me what configurations I need to make to access http://myhost from all PC's ?

Comment: What DNS resolver are your PCs configured to use? Is there a local DNS server or are you using the ISPs?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you can access the webserver on `192.168.0.140` through the IP itself from other system in your LAN.

If you can access webserver from other machines with IP, make appropriate entry in each system's `/etc/hosts` for `192.168.0.140` with `myhost`

If other systems in your LAN are windows, make appropriate entry in `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

If you don't like this method need to setup DNS server. In that case, I suggest `BIND`.

Comment: yes  I can access the Ip address (192.168.0.140 )from my MAC .But how will i edit it in /etc/hosts in MAC ?

Comment: Check this link. It may help you. http://unlettered.org/2008/03/06/fast-switching-your-etchosts-file-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box CentOS is configured to have the [iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) firewall running. By default it doesn't allow traffic on port 80 so you will have to enable it.

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo /sbin/service iptables save
```

As Peter says, if you want to access the server by name then you will also need to add it to your name service. If you only have a small number of PCs and the changes are infrequent then it is probably easier to just add an entry in the hosts file of each one.